# Does OAUth 2 allow authentication without UI (to an account with hard coded credentials)?

Tags: authentication, oauth

**Note:** this question is not about authenticating to an account after receiving a valid access token. This is about the first leg in the authentication process that would obtain the valid access token.

I am working on a web app that needs to connect to a specific box.com account. One of the requirements is that this connecting to box.com should happen purely in the background, using credentials that are hard coded into the web app.

So in other words this should authenticate user to a specific box.com account without asking the user to enter any account credentials.

Now, after asking about this from Box support, their answer is that:

1. they only support OAuth 2, and
2. having a login process that happens purely in the background should
   be possible with OAuth 2, but
3. that their help desk formally only supports login processes that
   require user to enter credentials through a UI. They do not have any
   documentation showing how to authenticate with hard coded
   credentials.

Being that they said that this should be possible, but since they cannot provide any documentation on this, I decided to look into if I can find information on this elsewhere.

My problem is that it looks like with OAuth the initial authentication always has to be through a UI. Is this correct? Or is there a way to set OAuth to authenticate against harc-coded credentials purely in the background, and if so, how?

Comment: Yes, you can use the API using hardcoded credentials. And I am voting to move the question to StackOverflow, as this is a programming issue, not a security one.

Comment: Have a look at [2 legged OAth](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

box.com does not - at least officially - support "2 legged OAuth" (aka "2LO") but they have a new feature (which may still be in Beta) to support authentication using JSON Web Tokens (JWT).

Here's their description on how JWT authentication works:

> This process replaces the first leg of the standard 3-legged OAuth
>   process in which the user grants an application permission to the
>   user’s Box account. Your service will authenticate by providing the
>   application ID, enterprise ID, token type, and sign it using a private
>   key. Box will then verify the identity of the application using a
>   public key from the private key pair.

You can find more information on their developer page, here:
https://developers.box.com/developer-edition/